# C#: Map screen absolute to relative screen coordinates in multiple screen environment

Tags: c#, screen, coordinates

I need a way to map some absolutes coordinates (relative to main screen) to relative coordinates to some screen.

For example, if you have two screens configured, if the main screen is the one of the right, there are some valid negative coordinates that point to the left screen. I need to convert these absolute coordinates always to a positive number relative to the left screen.

Edit: the goal is to know if some absolute coordinates are valid in some available screen using

```
    Screen.WorkingArea.Contains(thePoint),
```

iterating over the available screens.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need *positive* coordinates to reach your goal? The `Screen.WorkingArea.Contains` method would work for negative coordinates too.

Comment: The method doesn't return true for any of my two screen when I use negative coordinates

Comment: If the `Screen.WorkingArea` has negative coordinates and `thePoint` has negative coordinates, but the `Contains` returns `false`, the only answer is that the point doesn't belong to the `WorkingArea`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes!, the method was failing when the top left screen of my form is outside the left screen. Y have to check if the whole form intersects with the working area. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do for any screen configuration:

```
static Point GetRelativeCoordinates(Point absoluteCoordinates)
{
    var screen = Screen.FromPoint(absoluteCoordinates);
    return new Point(absoluteCoordinates.X - screen.Bounds.Left, absoluteCoordinates.Y - screen.Bounds.Top);
}
```

The `Bound` property stores the absolute coordinates of the `Top` and `Left` corners of the screen (`[0, 0]` being the top, left of the primary screen) so converting absolute coordinates to relative ones is pretty straightforward no matter how many screens you have.

I haven't tested the code but it *should* work.

Comment: Yes. But in this case I wanted to test if the point is contained in some screen. The method Screen.FromPoint returns de closest screen although the point is outside of every screen. But the function I was using make the trick. Thanks